# In OS X, how do I enter a second-plane Unicode character with the standard input method editor?

Tags: macos, unicode, input, astral-plane

I want to test that my Cocoa app properly handles input outside the basic multilingual plane, and copy-pasting it is out of the question. I don't know how to key in a character outside BMP! I have set up Japanese as an input source and am able to get random Katakana or Hiragana by typing Japanese-sounding words, but that trick won't work for plane 2 characters. Pasting characters in dismisses the input method editor, so that doesn't work either. I think I actually need to enter the correct keystrokes on my US English keyboard into some language's input source (Chinese, presumably, would be a good choice). In case it's not obvious, I don't speak any Asian languages.

Here's an example of some characters in the second plane: http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/UnihanGrid.pl?codepoint=20000

Any unicode character above 0xffff would be acceptable for my purposes as long as I can render the glyph with a font I have or can get for free.

Comment: You can use Ctr+Cmd+Space to quickly open Character Viewer. Click the top-right button to switch to extended mode, then click the ⚙️  button > *Customize list* in order to add the Unicode sets you are interested in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily manually enter any Unicode character by enabling the `Character Viewer` panel.  In OS X 10.6, go to `System Preferences -> Language & Text -> Input Sources` and in the list of input methods on the left, click enable `Keyboard & Character Viewer` and on the right side, `Show Input menu in menu bar`.  That should add an item to the upper right side of the standard OS X menu bar.  You can then click on it to select the Character Viewer.  In the panel that appears, select `View -> Code Tables`.  Then, in the `Unicode` tab, you can scroll down to any code point, including those outside the BMP.  Select that character and click on `Insert` to insert it into a text field like this one: .

Comment: (I hope I didn't write something impolite there!)

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks, Ned! Here is a plane 2 Chinese character as a gift of thanks: 卉

Comment: Great!  An even better gift would be to mark the answer as accepted.  That way we both enhance our reputations.